# Fixing AngularJS datetimepicker, using the same date for two inputs has a bug

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker, angular-directive

I'm using [this](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker) datetimepicker for AngularJS. My requirement is that I'll have to have a date and a separate time input. This works fine so far.

The true issue now is that when a date and time is selected and I then change the date it overrides the time. So when my time was 12:05:00 it will be reset to 00:00:00 because the datetimepicker generates a date but obviously is ignoring the time, it simply skips that part because it thinks you only need year, month and day.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FiQzPx9XYOkZDrmJGmnP)

```
  <body ng-controller="TestController">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Start Date</label>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="startDate" role="button"
                    data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="#">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input
                          restrict-input 
                          date-parser="YYYY-MM-DD"
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control"
                            data-ng-model="task.start_date">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                    <datetimepicker
                        data-ng-model="task.start_date"
                        data-datetimepicker-config="{startView: 'year', minView: 'day', dropdownSelector: '#startDate' }"
                    />
                </ul>
            </div>
            <label>Start Time</label>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="startTime" role="button"
                   data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="#">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input
                          date-parser="HH:mm:ss"
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control"
                            data-ng-model="task.start_date">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
                    <datetimepicker
                        data-on-set-time="onTimeSet(newDate, oldDate, 'start_date')"
                        data-ng-model="task.start_date"
                        data-datetimepicker-config="{startView: 'hour', dropdownSelector: '#startTime' }"
                    />
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <pre>{{task | json}}</pre>
  </body>
```

I'm pretty sure the issue is somewhere in [dateFactory line 168](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/src/js/datetimepicker.js#L161). To be more specific, when you debug the date values [around line 286](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/src/js/datetimepicker.js#L286) it seems like it gets lost there. Yes, in the "hour" function, not day as you expect. It seems to me like the directive is passing the state through and when it reaches hour it will detect that the maxView was day and set the time.

My issue is now simply that I couldn't figure out where exactly the issue is caused. Any help with that is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to add something like this to your scope:

```
$scope.onSetDate = function(newDate, oldDate) {
    if (typeof oldDate == 'string') {
        oldDate = new Date(oldDate);
    }
    newDate.setHours(oldDate.getHours());
    newDate.setMinutes(oldDate.getMinutes());
    newDate.setSeconds(oldDate.getSeconds());
}
```

and in your html:

```
<datetimepicker
    data-ng-model="task.start_date"
    data-datetimepicker-config="{startView: 'year', minView: 'day', dropdownSelector: '#startDate' }"
    on-set-time="onSetDate(newDate, oldDate)"
/>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/TTVC9aBCoQY1Dcm0nryY?p=preview

Comment: I support this solution because: once the day function (of datefactory) gets called, the result's `nextView` is set directly to `setTime` because of configuration minView = 'day', this parameter prevent model to keep the correct time

Comment: Thank you! :) I still hope this gets fixed in the directive itself.

Comment: Meh, this won't work as soon as you do `start_date: '2012-12-12 12:12:12',` instead of using `null` as value for the start date. It will behave wrong again as it did before. Checking if its a string and turning it into a date might fix it, trying it now.